# How do I include a built *.mk into Makefile more idiomatically? Also why `.PHONY: .DEFAULT` fails?

Tags: makefile, include, gnu-make

I want `make` to build something and reuse some of generated makefiles as an include.

Here is simplified model of what I have so far:

### Makefile

```
all: myprogram

.PHONY: .DEFAULT

.DEFAULT:
    ${MAKE} something_tricky.mk
    ${MAKE} -f actual_makefikle.mk $@

.SUFFIXES:

something_tricky.mk:
        echo "TRICKY_VARIABLE=qwerty" > something_tricky.mk
```

### actual_makefile.mk

```
include something_tricky.mk
all: myprogram

myprogram:
        echo ${TRICKY_VARIABLE} > $@
```

It sometihng like works, but has problems. For example `.PHONY: .DEFAULT` doesn't work, so I can't automatically rebuild any file.

My questions:

- How do I make `.PHONY: .DEFAULT` work?
- Is there any other way to delegate all targets to other Makefile (after building some dependencies of it)
- Are there any simpler and better patterns about such things that I don't know? (expect of abandoning Makefile-centric approach and embracing more high-level build system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make will automatically attempt to remake any included makefiles, and then start over. The following should work

```
include something_tricky.mk

.PHONY: all
all: myprogram

myprogram: $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
    echo $(TRICKY_VARIABLE) > $@

something_tricky.mk:
    echo TRICKY_VARIABLE=qwerty > something_tricky.mk
```

Comment: Thanks. `.PHONY` is not needed then. I though failure to `include` is a stopper error.

Comment: @Vi. Failing to include a file will only stop make if the file doesn't exist, or if make doesn't know how to make it, which isn't the case here because we've provided a rule to make `something_tricky.mk`.

Comment: @Vi. `all` should still be a `PHONY` recipe, although the rule itself isn't strictly necessary for this makefile, you could simply put `myprogram` as the first target instead.

Comment: What fails without `.PHONY: all` and why is it required? I tried without it and it seemed to work... Or you mean `all` should always be `.PHONY` regarless of this target-include combination?

Comment: @Vi. It's just a precaution, any target that doesn't actually make a file with the name of that target should be `PHONY`. If for whatever reason the makefile folder had a file named `all` the rule would stop working.

Comment: I though `touch all` is a legitimate hack to gag a makefile.

Comment: @Vi. Why would you want to do that?